# Loading ViewController via IBAction

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, viewcontroller, ibaction

I have an IBAction in my project, when user presses button, it should load a new view controller, however the code seems to be crashing

My code is as follows:

```
- (IBAction)PurchaseItem:(id)sender {
    PurchasedViewController *purchaseContr = (PurchasedViewController *)
        [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ShowAd"];

    _purchaseController.productID = @"com.id";

    purchaseContr.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

    [self presentViewController:purchaseContr animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

When I run the app on the device and press the button, the app crashed on the following line:

```
[self presentViewController:purchaseContr animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

The message I Have got is 'Thread 1: breakpoint 1.3'

My Crashlog is:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why are you using storyboards and not using segues?  Also... have you set a breakpoint manually that is causing your app to "crash"?

Comment: How should I change it to use segues?

Comment: Hi Omar! you still have not solved this problem? ok you can post the entire crash log?

Comment: @Ilario Still not working! I tried the code in the answer below, see my comments on that

Comment: Can you take a screen shot that shows the line numbers?  I think you may have set a breakpoint possibly...

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the right way to use Storyboards and Segues...

1. In your storyboard, hold `CTRL` and click-drag from the originating view controller to the destination view controller.  This creates and unnamed segue from A to B.
2. Click on the line that was just created, and in the settings for your segue, change it to Modal (since that's the kind you appear to want in this case), and give your segue a descriptive name (you're using "ShowAD" in the code in the question, which is okay).  You can also set the modal transitional style in interface builder, I believe.
3. Make your button click action look like this

---

```
-(IBAction)purchasItem:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowAD" sender:self];
}
```

Now, to set a property on the destination view controller, add another method to your originating view controller as such:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowAD"]) {
        PurchasedViewController *purchaseContr = [segue 
            destinationViewController];
        purchaseContr.productID = @"com.id";
    }
}
```

---

Now... with all this said, I think the problem actually is that you've manually set a break point.  If you've got a little blue arrowish thing where the line numbers are, that's a manually added breakpoint.  It stops your program execution at that line... but it's not a crash.  You can right click the breakpoint and click "disable" or "delete" breakpoint, and it'll "fix" your "crash".

Comment: Thank you but Im getting a Thread 1: Breakpoint on the line [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowAD" sender:self]; I haven't set any breakpoints manually

Comment: Did you go through the steps in the interface builder (storyboard) I mentioned?

Comment: On step 1. do I need to ctrl+drag the storyboard to the storyboard or the button to the storyboard to create the segue? I ctrl+drag the button to the storyboard

Comment: I ctrl+drag from storyboard to storyboard.  It gives you more control.  Dragging from button is fine, however if you do, then you need to get read of `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowAD" sender:self];` as your button will already call this method.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a crash, it looks like a manually set breakpoint! Disable all breakpoints in Xcode and run again.